# Traffic generator through proxy

Tags: node.js, haproxy, nightmare

I am trying to automate opening web page and run it through a local proxy
I have used this docker image
`docker pull zeta0/alpine-tor:latest`
and run it with this command:
`docker run -d -p 5566:5566 -p 2090:2090 -e tors=25 zeta0/alpine-tor`

I can see that the local proxy is working because I tested it with curl with this command:
`curl --socks5 localhost:5566 http://httpbin.org/ip` I get a response with a random IP address, different from my IP address.

I am using NightmareJS to open a browser window. I initialize the nightmare object as follows:

```
 const proxyNightmare = nightmare({
  executionTimeout: 1000000, // in ms
  waitTimeout: 1000000, // in ms  
  switches: {
   'proxy-server': proxy, // set the proxy server here ... 
   'ignore-certificate-errors': true
  },
  width: randomScreenElement[0],
  height: randomScreenElement[1],
  show: true
 });
```

and after that i open a new browser window with the following code:

```
const minimist = require('./node_modules/minimist');
const platform = require('./node_modules/platform');
const nightmare = require('./node_modules/nightmare');

let args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
 alias: {
  ur: 'url',
  px: 'proxy',
  pt: 'port',
  us: 'user',
  ps: 'pass',
  ws: 'windows',
  te: 'time',
  re: 'referrals'
 },
 default: {
  url: 'https://testsite.com', // Url to navigate
  proxy: 'http://localhost', // Proxy address 1.127.0.1, localhost or example.com
  port: '5566', // Proxy port
  user: '', // Proxy username
  pass: '', // Proxy pass
  windows: '1', // Total of windows to be opened
  time: '3', // Total time of the section in minutes
  referrals: 'no'
 }
});

// console.log('args:', args);

const openWebsite = async id => {
 'use strict';
 let url = args.url, screenArray;
 let proxy = args.proxy ? args.proxy + ':' + args.port : '';
 let user = args.user;
 let pass = args.pass;
 let miliseconds = (args.time == 'random') ? randomTimeFromInterval(60, 300) : (args.time * 6000) / 6;
 let userAgentObj = require("./useragent/most-common.json");
 let obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userAgentObj));
 let ua = obj.randomElement().ua;
 let info = platform.parse(ua); // Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7.2; en; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0 Opera 11.52
 let osFamily = info.os.family; // Android, IOS, Linux, etc..
 let blacklist = [
  'https://www.facebook.com/ppplayermusic',
  'https://instagram.com/ppplayermusic',
  'https://ppplayer.com/public/search',
  'https://ppplayer.com/search',
  'https://ppplayer.com/login',
  'https://ppplayer.com/register'
 ];

 let randomScreenElement = screenArray.randomElement();

 const proxyNightmare = nightmare({
  executionTimeout: 1000000, // in ms
  waitTimeout: 1000000, // in ms  
  switches: {
   'proxy-server': proxy, // set the proxy server here ... 
   'ignore-certificate-errors': true
  },
  width: randomScreenElement[0],
  height: randomScreenElement[1],
  show: true
 });

 let gotourl, addtourl;
 let utm_source = ['Google', 'facebook', 'twitter', 'instagram', 'Bing', 'Yahoo', 'DuckDuckGo', 'LinkedIn', 'Reddit', 'DuckDuckGo', 'Quora']
 let utm_medium = ['cpc', 'Organic'];
 let utm_campaign = ['', ''];
 let utm_term = ['ppplayer', 'ppplayer+music', 'music', 'online', 'listen+online+music', 'ppplayer+online', 'play+music', 'digital', 'ppplayer+playlist', 'artist', 'playlist', 'ppplayer+web'];


 url = (addtourl != '' && args.referrals == 'yes') ? url + addtourl : url;
 // GO
 try {
  await proxyNightmare
   .authentication(user, pass)
   .useragent(ua)
   .goto(url)
   .wait(miliseconds)
   .evaluate((miliseconds, blacklist) => {
   }, miliseconds, blacklist)
   .wait(miliseconds)
   .wait(miliseconds)
   .end()
   .then(function (result) {
    console.log("result=>: " + result);
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Error->:', error);
   });

 } catch (e) {
  console.error("Error+>: ", e);
 }
}

for (var i = 0; i < args.windows; i++) {
 openWebsite(i)
  .then(a => console.dir(a))
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
}
```

When I run the `openWebsite` function, I get the error code -111 `ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED`

Any ideas?